# Compare rows in RDD

Tags: scala, for-loop, apache-spark, rdd

How can I iterate through RDD rows and compare one row to the next one in the RDD?

I know I can use for loop in the following way : for(x<-rddItems), is there any way to do something like x.next() inside the for loop? or to use some index inside the for?

thanks

Comment: How are you gonna do it if rows are not ordered and result depends from run to run?

Comment: I created a sorted RDD

Comment: @ipoteka: RDDs are ordered and unless you shuffle them, the order will be the same from run to run.

Comment: @Lital: Can you describe what sort of output you're looking for? Just comparing items has no effect, so it's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: unless you join, repartition them, etc. @Lital So it would be better if you suply rdd's with keys and join\make cartesian product with these keys.

Comment: @DanielDarabos . More information: I have a pairRDD (key,values) for each key I have one or more values. I need to choose only one value for each key. For each key, I need to go through all the values (that are sorted by time) and compare them. The output should be a new RDD (or List) that contain the key,value pairs (but only one value for each key).

Comment: In that case you would be better served by `groupByKey` or `reduceByKey`, like @ipoteka suggests. It should also be faster than sorting!

Comment: @DanielDarabos I already using groupByKey. but now I want to iterate through the values within each group and compare it to the next value in the same group. meaning I'm using for((k,v)<-myGroupedbyKeyRDD) but inside the for loop (which iterating through the groups) I would like to go through the values and compare each one to the next value in the group.

Comment: Oh, why not ask about that then? :D After you sort the group, you can do the same sort of thing with the `for` loop in the answers below, or you can use `seq.sliding` or `seq.zip(seq.tail)` to get pairs of elements that follow each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using `mapPartitions`:

```
rdd.mapPartitions { partition =>
  var previous = partition.next
  for (element <- partition) yield {
    val result = previous == element // Do your comparison.
    previous = element
    result
  }
}
```

But this does not compare the last element of partition N with the first element of partition N+1. It would be quite complicated to do that and would hurt performance. So I'm just crossing my fingers and hope you're okay with missing some comparisons!

Comment: Quite late to the party: wouldn't this throw a NullPointerException?

Comment: If you think it would, please explain. Obviously I don't think it would, or I would not have posted it as an answer :). Thanks.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Spark, so that was a mostly a question, not a remark. Shouldn't there be a check on `partiton.hasNext`?

Comment: `for (x <- iterator)` will check `hasNext` and stop appropriately.

Comment: @DanielDaraos I'm new to Scala too. Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each individual partition of the RDD using mapPartitions, something like:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1,73,5,226))
rdd.mapPartitions { iter =>

  var last = 0
  var result = List[Boolean]()
  while (iter.hasNext) {
    val current = iter.next
    result = result ::: List(current > last)
    last = current
  }

  result.iterator
}.collect().foreach(println)
```

Gives:

> true
>   true
>   false
>   true

This is done on a partition by partition basis, not through the entire RDD.

Comment: You can see the difference by playing with partitions (second arg in sc.parallelize). This only gives the answer you say if partitions is set to 1

Comment: Yeah - in many cases, you will want to e.g. use a HashPartitioner on some pertinent parameter before doing this, rather than setting partitions to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a key and then join the rdd to itself (applying your offset).

Comment: That's seems an elegant solution, how would you do that ?

Answer (score -1):

I have thought of this possibility , I am unsure it is really a good one ?

```
def diff_timestamp(liste):
    timestamps = liste
    r          = []
    values     = []
    for indice, valeur in enumerate(timestamps):
        values.append(float(valeur))
        if indice>0:
            delta = values[indice] - values[indice-1]
            r.append(delta)
    return r
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question, which is asking about Spark and RDDs which work very differently from python lists.